# Create a method which returns value from MySQL and does query in Async thread

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, bukkit

I'm developing Minecraft plugin using Bukkit API.
I want to check if the player is registered with custom static method.

```
static boolean isRegistered(String username)
```

This method should do MySQL query (SELECT) and return true/false appropriately. To avoid lagging main thread, I would like to execute that query in Async thread inside this method. Bukkit implements Runnable called `BukkitRunnable`, which is used like this:

```
static boolean isRegistered(String username) {
  new BukkitRunnable() {
    /* MySQL code here */
  }.runTaskAsynchronously(this);
}
```

so from outside of this method we don't know what this method does inside. We just want to get true if player is registered and we don't care how this method does it.

Now, let's say that this method is part of API which provides some methods like `isRegistered`, so we don't know where it will be called from.

My question is: How can I properly return true/false from my `isRegistered` method without forcing main thread to wait before query finishes?

Comment: You cannot `return` a `boolean` _and_ run the task asynchronously - this is nonsense - you cannot eat your cake and have it too. You **either** need to have a return type of `Future<Boolean>` and run async **or**  have a return type of `boolean` and run sync. If the executing code is waiting for a `boolean` then it will wait until it gets one (or an `Exception`)...

Comment: Well, If I had two cakes, I can eat it and one remains. But seriosly, can you post an example with Future<>? Never heard of this, all ppl from Bukkit was talking something about Callbacks... but I'm still newbie in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this but it's not really recommanded :

```
public boolean isRegistered(final String name) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<Boolean> result = executor.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public synchronized Boolean call() throws Exception {
            // DO SOMETHING
            return true;
        }
    });
    try {
        return result.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this solution can not work asynchronously. Because you are waiting answer at result.get(). He don't want to wait until it finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create interface for when async task end. I have written code snippet for this.

**ResponseListener.java**

```
interface IResponseListener {
    void response(ResponseEvent event);
}
```

**ResponseEvent.java**

```
public class ResponseEvent {

   private Object response;

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public <T> T getResponse() {
       return (T)response;
   }

   public <T> void setResponse(T response) {
       this.response = response;
   }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
    static void isRegistered(String username, IResponseListener listener) {
       new BukkitRunnable() {
            /* MySQL code here */
            Boolean isRegistered = userRepository.isRegistered();
            ResponseEvent event = new ResponseEvent();
            event.setResponse(isRegistered);
            listener.response(event);
       }.runTaskAsynchronously(this);
    }

    isRegistered("userName", new IResponseListener() {
        public void response(ResponseEvent event) {
            Boolean response = event.getResponse();
            if(response) {
                 //Do registered user stuff
            } else {
                 //Do unregistered user stuff
            }
        } 
    });
```

Please note that you will get a `ClassCastException` if your type is something other than what you expect it to be.